# Email address in Email Services

Tags: apex-email-service

I would like a confirmation. All the info I found is always with the email address.

If I have an 'Email Service' with an APEX class associated, but I don't have set an email address. The service is NOT working, isn´t it? I mean, we always need the email address to execute the class or it can be executed in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apex email service works on the concept of association of apex class with 1 or emails

> You can associate each email service with one or more
> Salesforce-generated email addresses to which users can send messages
> for processing. To give multiple users access to a single email
> service, you can: Associate multiple Salesforce-generated email
> addresses with the email service and allocate those addresses to
> users. Associate a single Salesforce-generated email address with the
> email service, and write an Apex class that executes according to the
> user accessing the email service. For example, you can write an Apex
> class that identifies the user based on the user's email address and
> creates records on behalf of that user.

More on it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm).

To answer your question, if you don't send email to 1 of the associated email address it wont trigger the apex email service.